# SHA-256: One input, two different outputs?

Tags: hash, sha-256

I am new to SHA-256.  I have discovered that the same input could produce different SHA-256 hash ouputs depending on the (online) device I chose for generating the hash.

Is this normal, or is there a problem on one of the devices I used?

Edit: If I get it right, there might be an encoding issue that makes it possible to have two different outputs for the same input. .. But, are these two different outputs BOTH valid SHA-256 hashes ? Can I say this, or not ? Or, is one of these two different outputs a "false sha-256" hash? And if yes, how to sort them in order to make sure of using the "real" one?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They probably use different character encodings or some include a NULL terminator or something like that... In principle SHA-256 is a well-defined deterministic function that should always yield the same output upon the same input.

Comment: I have the same experience once in a while. You can depend on the command of 'sha256sum /path/to/file' in a Linux terminal.

Comment: Yeah, but remember that command returns a hexadecimal *representation* of the binary hash value and some additional info. The actual hash is what you get if you decode the hexadecimals to bytes again.

Comment: @Maarten Hexadecimal is no less accurate a representative of bytes as whatever else you are thinking of...

Comment: For humans, sure. The actual *bytes* are the best representation for computers. I just made this note because if you'd have to feed the people that use the ASCII representation of the hexadecimals as hash value, you'd have a problem.

Comment: Anyway, this has to be an encodings issue. The same binary input produces always the same binary output.

Comment: @everyone : thanks for your kind answers :)
If I get it right, there might be an encoding issue that makes it possible to have two different outputs for the same input. .. But, are these two different outputs BOTH SHA-256 hashes ? Can I say this, or not ? Or, is one of these two different outputs a "false sha-256" hash? And if yes, how to sort them in order to make sure of using the "real" one?

Comment: Well, if you want full answers give all the details: input string, both programs that produce a hash (plus OS-settings, encoding settings etc.) or we can only guess.

Comment: That's just one, and it works correctly for the input `abc` (it gives the hexadecimal representation of the SHA256 digest as `ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad` which I could confirm by openssl on my system via `echo -n "abc" | openssl sha256`

Comment: @HennoBrandsma
Thank you for your answer Henno.
Here is my example:

I selected 3 different (by pure chance) online sha256 generator:

https://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator
https://hashgenerator.de/
https://tools.keycdn.com/sha256-online-generator

When the input is "123456" (without cotation marks), they all produce the same sha256 hash. But when the input is something like a long text of Lorem Ipsum (5 paragraphs), then you get 3 different sha256 hashes!

Comment: Probably they're ignoring whitespace in different ways, or use different input encodings. Or the fomatting of the input text is still there in some tags... If the **raw byte input** of these tools would have been the same, so would their hashes have been. If the tools use js you could look at the preprocessing code..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma
Thank you. Would you agree with my conclusion: it is possible to have different valid sha256 hashes for the very same input?

Comment: No, definitely not: do not trust online hashing tools is the moral here.

Comment: Well, then you desagree with @Meir Maor too, don't you? (sorry for bothering you, I'm a novice and new to SHA-256... and I don't know much about computing science...)
Should I comprehend that there is ONE pure method for creating a SHA-256 hash that define clearly the encoding (and everything...) of the input and, consequently, that any other method would produce a false sha256 hash?

Comment: No, the hash has simply be defined to be over bits / bytes. How you get these bits / bytes is *not* defined by the hashing method. Certifiates, for example, are signed using a signature method that always includes the hashing of the data. To be sure that the input is always identical they use an encoding method called DER, *distinguished* encoding rules, that make sure that there is always a *canonical* representation of the data presented to the hash method during signature generation *and* signature verification.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes

Thank you Maarten, but I did not understand your answer. If there is NOT one method to produce a valid sha256 for a given input, then different methods could produce different valid sha256 for this same given input, yes? no?

Could someone take a clear position on this simple question: could there be several valid sha256 hashes for a same/single/identical input?

That would really be helpful!

Comment: You're a programmer, right? If you have a method `sha256` with one parameter, a byte array. Then yes, for each specific byte array you will get the same result. However, if you have any other input rather than a byte array (say `byte[]`) then you'll first have to convert that to a byte array. This conversion is **not** part of the function. So if you have a `string` then you have to convert to `byte[]`. Problem is: there are multiple conversion routines possible. That's likely your problem: the strings are identical, but the byte arrays are not.

Answer (score 4):

It is not normal.

If you are correct that the inputs are identical (same line termination, same character encoding, etc), and you're comparing the same kind of representation of the checksum (bits to bits, hex to hex, whatever), then there is a bug in one of the devices.

SHA-256 when it works correctly is a pure function. The SHA-256 hash of "123" must always be the 32 byte value that when encoded to hexadecimal is "a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3". If it isn't, there's a problem, either with the input being inadvertently transformed, or with the calculations.

Answer (score 3):

SHA-256 is defined at the bit/byte level. A given sequence of bytes has exactly one SHA-256 value. Any other would be incorrect.

However a given string instance may be encoded in different ways into a byte sequence. The string may differ in how whitespace is represented, or whitespace may be skipped. The characters in the text may also differ. All this may lead to different valid SHA-256 values for the same visible string.

For example non-ASCII characters may be encoded as a single byte in a language specific encoding or as two bytes in UTF8 or Unicode. All those encodings are equally "correct".

Comment: Thank you very much Meir! It's getting clearer for me :)
So, I can conclude that it is possible to have different valid sha256 hashes for the same input, can I?

Comment: @Gepetto No. The conclusion is that you're getting different hashes **because you're passing different inputs**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are some whitespace characters like line feed at the end of the line.